# How can i keep a dynamically added textbox after program closes in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void ADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox TxtBox = new TextBox();
    TxtBox.Name = "txtDynamic";
    TxtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 25);
    TxtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(224, 185);
    TxtBox.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
    TxtBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    TxtBox.Multiline = true;
    panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBox);
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear... what is the meaning of after program closes?
after closing the running application?

Comment: Keep where? You can save added textbox data in file or database or application settings and then retrieve on the next application start

Comment: Why would you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some kind of persisting mechanism for the data you have to persist, there's no way around that. Upon app startup you load persisted data and construct your forms as needed. 
`What` mechanism depends on numerous factors, you have to be able to decide this for yourself.